# disable ephemeral mount on /mnt for ubuntu on azure

Tags: cloud-init, azure

Ubuntu machines on azure got ephemeral disk that is being automatically mounted on /mnt

I don't want to have this ephemeral drive on /mnt but rather disable it or just move it to another location.

I've tried to achieve that with cloud-init like so:

```
mounts:
  - [/dev/sdb, null]
```

but that didn't help,
so I tried to edit waagent.conf and reboot that machine like so:
`sed -i '/s/ResourceDisk.MountPoint=.*/ResourceDisk.MountPoint=\/ephemeral/' /etc/waagent.conf`
but that didn't solve the issue either...

Ultimately I would like to solve it with cloud-init as I would like to mount another drive (persist data) on /mnt instead.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found myself a solution for not mounting of the drive, may be useful for somebody.

`/etc/fstab` is being rewritten on each start. There are options in `/etc/waagent.conf` that will affect, how it is done. They start with `ResourceDisk.`, list is available i.e. here https://github.com/Azure/WALinuxAgent below in README.

There is however no option to turn off the mount (AFAIK). But, it can still be done. I simply turned off formatting of the ResourceDisk by setting `ResourceDisk.Format=n` and I had to deconstruct the already formatted partition of the temporary drive.

I personally like visual tools more, so I used `cfdisk /dev/sdb` as root and deleted the partition. BE CAREFUL THERE, THE DEVICE MAY NOT BE `/dev/sdb` IN THE FUTURE.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to change the mount point location /mnt to other then you need to make correction in /mnt to /data and reboot the server and it's working perfectly without any issue.

root@ubuntutestingvm:~# cat /etc/fstab 

# CLOUD_IMG: This file was created/modified by the Cloud Image build process

UUID=879b9943-72cc-4f03-b0c7-26ef2c4aa232       /        ext4   defaults,discard        0 0

/dev/disk/cloud/azure_resource-part1    **/data**   auto    defaults,nofail,x-systemd.requires=cloud-init.service,comment=cloudconfig      0       2

see the attached screenshot.

[Azure Ubuntu Mount point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2f11Q.jpg)